# Random choice in Anylogic

Tags: random, anylogic

I want to select a random number from [0,1,2,3] in a probability of [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4] in anylogic. This can be easily done in Python by using numpy.random.choice. However, I couldn't find someway to do this in anylogic. I don't want to use the customized distribution since I want to apply it to many agents in different parameters.

I am looking for someway to do this in anylogic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with customDistributions

[image: cd]

YOu can just get the value by calling `customDistribution()`

If you want to do it in a more flexible way:
Create a variable called cd in your agent of type CustomDistribution and then you can do something like this:

```
int[]x={0,1,2,3,4};//you need an extra number to complete the interval
double[]y={0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0};//extra number has probability 0
cd=new CustomDistribution(x,y,new Random());
```

to get the random value you do

```
roundToInt(cd.get(new Random()));
```

Comment: Thanks. But Sorry that I don't want to use the custom distribution since I want to apply it to many agents in different parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the updating. It helps a lot.